# Eliminar caracteres y pasar texto a .txt por líneas en Python

Tags: python

Tengo un proyecto entre manos que consiste en lo siguiente:
Uso 'pytesseract' para sacar los datos de un ticket, esto me genera un string con todo el texto del ticket pero me interesa, para un futuro uso, eliminar ciertos caracteres de ese string generado.

La primera parte del proyecto funciona como debería:

```
from PIL import Image
import pytesseract
print ("Lector de Tickets")

img = Image.open("foto.jpg")
pytesseract.pytesseract.tesseract_cmd = 'C:/Program Files (x86)/Tesseract-OCR/tesseract'

result = pytesseract.image_to_string(img)
print(result)
```

'foto.jpg' seria una foto del ticket que se encuentra en la misma carpeta que el proyecto, y el resultado es una string con todos los datos.

Ahora, intento eliminar caracteres especiales (*,-,@,:,etc.) y, además, sustituir las comas por puntos. Esto último es lo más importante ya que el ticket esta compuesto por:

> Nombre_del_producto   Cantidad   Precio   Código

Como las strings en Python son inmutables, entiendo que debo crear una nueva string y mediante 'replace' sustituir cada uno de los caracteres y este será el string que guarde luego en un .txt. Sin embargo tengo problemas en esta parte. He intentado varias cosas:

```
for linea in final:
    #Copiar el texto a la nueva string
    #AQUÍ ES DONDE TENGO DUDAS

    #Eliminar caracteres especiales
    final = linea.replace("-", "")
    final = linea.replace("*", "")
    final = linea.replace(":", "")
    final = linea.replace("/", "")
    final = linea.replace("%", "")
    final = linea.replace("$", "")
    final = linea.replace("&", "")
    final = linea.replace("(", "")
    #Esto sigue con más caracteres...

    #Ahora cambiar comas por puntos
    final = linea.replace(",",".")
```

¿Sabeis aportar una solución a esto?
Un saludo,

PD: Adjunto una foto del resultado del programa tras recibir el ticket.

[image: Foto del resultado.]

--

Actualización:

El proyecto queda así tras la respuesta de Marcos:

```
from PIL import Image
import pytesseract
import re
print ("Lector de Tickets")

img = Image.open("foto.jpg")
pytesseract.pytesseract.tesseract_cmd = 'C:/Program Files (x86)/Tesseract-OCR/tesseract'

result = pytesseract.image_to_string(img)
print(result)

final = re.sub('[^\d.a-zA-Z ]','',re.sub(",", ".", result))
print(final)
```

Mi duda original queda disipada pero me surgue una nueva pregunta. El resultado ahora queda, parcialmente, como interesa:

> CERVEZA FRANZISKANER 1x 5.95 5.95 CLIMPIADOR VINAGRE 1L 1x 0.75 . 0.75 CMONSTER BEBIDA ENERG 1x 1.00 1.00 BACEITUNA RANCH 150G 1x 0.55 0.55 BARROZ REDUNDO EXTRA 1x 0.72 0.72 etc.......

Ya nos hemos quitado de enmedio los símbolos y hemos sustituido las comas por puntos. Ahora la idea es, pasar todo eso a un fichero .txt pero debe ser 'línea a línea'. Es decir que el fichero final debería ser algo así:

- CERVEZA FRANZISKANER 1x 5.95 5.95
- CLIMPIADOR VINAGRE 1L 1x 0.75 . 0.75
- CMONSTER BEBIDA ENERG 1x 1.00 1.00
- etc....

La finalidad de esta organización es poder sumar luego cantidades entre otras operaciones. Se me ocurre un bucle for línea a línea pero para ello debería usar 'split' para separar las líneas por espacios; esto plantea un problema ya que el formato es:

> CERVEZA FRANZISKANER 1x 5.95 5.95

¿Alguna solución?

Comment: Trata de no actualizar con una nueva pregunta, sino de generar otro post con esa nueva pregunta. De todas maneras trataré de ayudarte.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Es un buen día para usar expresiones regulares. Python te permite hace operaciones con expresiones regulares con el módulo `re`.

```
>>> import re
>>> cadena = "(palabra1 ,*,-,@,y/:,palabra2_-"
>>> x = re.sub(r'[^\w]+', '', cadena)
>>> print x
'palabra1ypalabra2_'
>>> y = re.sub(r'[^\da-zA-Z]+', '', cadena)
>>> print y
'palabra1ypalabra2'
```

La función `sub` sustituye los caracteres que coincidan con el patrón, en el primer parametro, con lo puesto en el reemplazo, en el segundo parámetro, de la cadena pasada por el tercer parámetro.

> sub(pattern, repl, string, count=0, flags=0)

Nota como en el caso de la clase de caracter `\w` esta permite los guiones bajos `_`, por eso puse la otra expresión regular `[^\da-zA-Z]+` para que sólo sea alfanumérico, si es eso lo que deseas.

Entonces podrías, 1. Reemplazar las comas por puntos, 2. Eliminar los caracteres no alfanuméricos (además de espacios y puntos, o como quieras).

```
>>> print cadena
(palabra1 ,*,-,@,y/:,palabra2_-
>>> nueva = re.sub(r'[^\d.a-zA-Z ]','',re.sub(",", ".", cadena))
>>> print nueva
palabra1 ....y.palabra2
```

### Actualización.

Debido a tu actualización de improvisto actualizo esta respuesta.
Lo que se me ocurre es que vuelvas a utilizar una expresión regular para encontrar un patrón que requieras.

Yo percibo, al menos por los datos que muestras, que hay uno de la forma `(digito)(espacio)(letra)`, entonces ahí puedes utilizar de nuevo el `re.sub`, insertar un salto de línea. Después guardar eso mismo en un archivo.

```
import re
import os

archivo_out = os.path.join(os.getcwd(), 'outfile.txt')

cadena = 'CERVEZA FRANZISKANER 1x 5.95 5.95 CLIMPIADOR VINAGRE 1L 1x 0.75 . 0.75 CMONSTER BEBIDA ENERG 1x 1.00 1.00 BACEITUNA RANCH 150G 1x 0.55 0.55 BARROZ REDUNDO EXTRA 1x 0.72 0.72'

patron = r'(\d [a-zA-Z])'
cadenas = re.sub(patron, r'\1\n', cadena)

with open(archivo_out, 'w') as outfile:
    outfile.write(cadenas)
```

Y el resultado da algo del estilo:

```
CERVEZA FRANZISKANER 1x 5.95 5.95 C
LIMPIADOR VINAGRE 1L 1x 0.75 . 0.75 C
MONSTER BEBIDA ENERG 1x 1.00 1.00 B
ACEITUNA RANCH 150G 1x 0.55 0.55 B
ARROZ REDUNDO EXTRA 1x 0.72 0.72
```

Lo delicado está en el patrón, ya que puede que una letra después del espacio en blanco no sea tan riguroso, o el número antes del espacio, etc.

### Nota sobre la expresión regular.

Es común que cuando "capturas" un patrón en una expresión regular, quieras utilizar lo capturado. Por ejemplo, una vez capturados `'(hola) (mundo)'`, quieras hacer algo con ellos; borrar, insertar, voltear. O por ejemplo, está el caso muy común de los formatos de fechas, `(\d{2})-(\d{2})-(\d{4})` que haría *match* con algo como `12-01-2015` que tiene el formato `dd-mm-yyyy` y lo quieres pasar a otro formato como `yyyy/mm/dd`, pues una vez capturados estos grupos, puedes utilizarlos a tu disposición utilizando referencias según el orden en que los pusiste, es decir, el primer `(\d{2})` sería el número 1, el siguiente grupo sería el 2 y, el `(\d{4})` sería el 3, etcétera. Para esto, necesitas de la sintaxis `\referencia`, es decir, el carácter de escape más el número al que hace referencia. Por lo que, para cambiar el formato de la fecha, utilizarías `\3/\2/\1` que convertiría la fecha pasada a la forma `2015/01/12`.

Bueno, ahora ya que sabemos que de algo como `(grupo1)(grupo2)(grupo3)` podemos modificarlo con `\1`, `\2`, `\3`, insertar caracteres en medio, omitir para eliminar, etc., entonces es así como funciona la función `sub` del módulo `re`. Un problema surge cuando ponemos el caracter `\`, porque este le dice a python que escape el caracter subsecuente, así como '\n' escapa un salto de línea, y estos caracteres son conocidos. Pero los desconocidos causan cosas extrañas, errores, etc,. y uno desconocido sería tal cual `\1` o `\2`, etc., que pasan a la función `sub` como escapados. Sin embargo, python permite que ciertas cadenas de texto sean tomadas como texto sin interpretación, logrando que cadenas de la forma `\1` sean tomadas literalmente y no se interpreten (escapen, por ejemplo) previamente y para eso se le añade una letra "r" al inicio, por ejemplo, `r'\1\n\3'`, lo que permite pasar sin escapar, a la función `sub` ese tipo de cadenas de forma literal, por lo que ahora si se puede hacer el eliminar el grupo 2 y poner entre el grupo 1 y el grupo 3 un salto de línea.`

Para ver lo que comento, corre el código tanto con `r` como sin esta, y en cada caso nota lo que se escribe en el archivo.

Comment: Gracias por la solución, aunque funciona como espero, no entiendo bien el funcionamiento de "re.sub(patron, r'\1\n\3', cadena)". Entiendo lo que hace .sub pero no acabo de entender que hace r'\1\n\3'.

Comment: Ya lo actualicé con una explicación que espero te sirva para comprenderlo. Cualquier cuestión referente a mi respuesta, no dudes en comentarlo. Si tienes otra duda, no dudes formular una pregunta nueva.

Comment: hola, en mi caso quiero eliminar todos los caracteres no alfanumericos a excepcion de los parentesis y los guienes bajos como me quedaria o como tendria que escribir la variable patron?

Comment: `r'[^\w()]'` Si te sirvió mi respuesta a esta pregunta, me harías un favor al votarla positivamente.