# Patrones en Python con expresiones regulares

Tags: python, python-3.x, regex

Intento encontrar la forma de, partiendo del texto de un ticket (generado por un OCR), separar el contenido del mismo para operar más tarde. El problema es, que el formato de los tickets no son constantes.

Hasta ahora, y con ayuda de un [post previo](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/248339/eliminar-caracteres-y-pasar-texto-a-txt-por-l%C3%ADneas-en-python) (gracias a Marco), llevo construido el siguiente código:

```
#Proyecto lector de Tickets
from PIL import Image
import pytesseract
import re
import os

print ("Lector de Tickets")
#Lee la imagen.
img = Image.open("foto.jpg")

#Transforma la imgen en texto.
pytesseract.pytesseract.tesseract_cmd = 'C:/Program Files (x86)/Tesseract-OCR/tesseract'
result = pytesseract.image_to_string(img)

#Muestra el texto resultante.
print(result)

#Elimina los caracteres especiales del texto y convierte las comas en puntos. Devuelve un string con los datos.
final = re.sub('[^\d.a-zA-Z ]','',re.sub(",", ".", result))

#Muestra los datos.
print(final)

#Creamos un patron del tipo:
#(digito)(espacio)(letra)
patron = '(\d)(\s)([a-zA-Z])'

#Comento esta línea porque forma parte de la duda.
#patron = '(\d)([a-zA-Z])(\s)(\d)(\s)(\d)(\s)([a-zA-Z])'

#Aplicamos el patron a los datos y los almacenamos en cadenas.
cadenas = re.sub(patron, r'\1\n\3', final)

#Pasamos los datos a un .txt
archivo_out = os.path.join(os.getcwd(), 'outfile.txt')

with open(archivo_out, 'w') as outfile:
    outfile.write(cadenas)
```

Aprovecho para aclarar que trabajo en Python 3.7.2. 
Adjunto ahora la foto del ticket original (el que recibe el programa) a continuación:

[image: Foto del ticket original.]

En este momento (edito la pregunta tras el comentario de abulafia para que sea más fácil de solucionar), el contenido de 'result' es el siguiente:

```
CERVEZA FRANZISKANER 1x 5.95 5,95 C
LIMPIADOR VINAGRE 1L 1x 0.75 , 0.75 C
MONSTER BEBIDA ENERG 1x 1,00 1,00 B
ACEITUNA R/ANCH 150G 1x 0,55 0,55 B
ARROZ REDUNDO EXTRA 1x 0,72 0,72 A
MAS REGANAS AC.0L 1x 0,66 0,66 B
PALOMITAS SAL MICRO 1x 0.79 0,79 B
BARRAS PRE00 UFERTA 1x 1,00 1,00 A
MAGGI PASTA URIENTAL 1x 1.50 1,50 B
BULSA BASURA IFA 1x 1.30 1,30 C
SALAMI REVILLAS 85 0 1x 0,95 0,95 B
SALCHICHON 85 GR 1x 0,95 0,95 B
FILETE PECHUGA PAVO 1x 4,42 4,42 B
ESTROPAJO INUXIDABLE 1): 0.45 0,45 0
CDRAZON RUMANA BJA 1x 1-49 1.49 A
ENSALADA 4 ESTACIUNE 1X 0-59 0,59 A
PIZZA JAMDN Y [JUESO ‘ 1x 1,75 1,75 B

ENSALADA 4 ESTACIONE 1x 0.59 0,59 A

TOTAL CDPRA . . . . . . . . . . . . . . 25.41
```

Y la variable 'final' tiene por valor:

```
CERVEZA FRANZISKANER 1x 5.95 5.95 CLIMPIADOR VINAGRE 1L 1x 0.75 . 0.75 CMONSTER BEBIDA ENERG 1x 1.00 1.00 BACEITUNA RANCH 150G 1x 0.55 0.55 BARROZ REDUNDO EXTRA 1x 0.72 0.72 AMAS REGANAS AC.0L 1x 0.66 0.66 BPALOMITAS SAL MICRO 1x 0.79 0.79 BBARRAS PRE00 UFERTA 1x 1.00 1.00 AMAGGI PASTA URIENTAL 1x 1.50 1.50 BBULSA BASURA IFA 1x 1.30 1.30 CSALAMI REVILLAS 85 0 1x 0.95 0.95 BSALCHICHON 85 GR 1x 0.95 0.95 BFILETE PECHUGA PAVO 1x 4.42 4.42 BESTROPAJO INUXIDABLE 1 0.45 0.45 0CDRAZON RUMANA BJA 1x 149 1.49 AENSALADA 4 ESTACIUNE 1X 059 0.59 APIZZA JAMDN Y JUESO  1x 1.75 1.75 BENSALADA 4 ESTACIONE 1x 0.59 0.59 ATOTAL CDPRA . . . . . . . . . . . . . . 25.41
```

Sin embargo, hasta ahora el resultado queda casí como nos gustaría pero tiene algunos fallos, causa del formato del ticket. Nos interesa un formato para el resultado tal que así:

> CERVEZA FRANZISKANER 1x 5.95 5.95 C

Pero algunas líneas quedan descuadradas debido a las irregularidades del formato del ticket original y el fichero .txt final queda así:

```
CERVEZA FRANZISKANER 1x 5.95 5.95
CLIMPIADOR VINAGRE 1L 1x 0.75 . 0.75
CMONSTER BEBIDA ENERG 1x 1.00 1.00
BACEITUNA RANCH 150G 1x 0.55 0.55
BARROZ REDUNDO EXTRA 1x 0.72 0.72
AMAS REGANAS AC.0L 1x 0.66 0.66
BPALOMITAS SAL MICRO 1x 0.79 0.79
BBARRAS PRE00
UFERTA 1x 1.00 1.00
AMAGGI PASTA URIENTAL 1x 1.50 1.50
BBULSA BASURA IFA 1x 1.30 1.30
CSALAMI REVILLAS 85 0 1x 0.95 0.95
BSALCHICHON 85
GR 1x 0.95 0.95
BFILETE PECHUGA PAVO 1x 4.42 4.42
BESTROPAJO INUXIDABLE 1 0.45 0.45 0CDRAZON RUMANA BJA 1x 149 1.49
AENSALADA 4
ESTACIUNE 1X 059 0.59
APIZZA JAMDN Y JUESO  1x 1.75 1.75
BENSALADA 4
ESTACIONE 1x 0.59 0.59
ATOTAL CDPRA . . . . . . . . . . . . . . 25.41
```

Como se puede apreciar, el último caracter presente en el ticket no debería estar al principio de la siguiente línea. Nos interesa un formato (como se ha mencionado antes) en el que quede:

> Nombre_del_producto Cantidad_x Precio_Unidad Precio_Final Código

De esta forma pretendo poder operar luego: sumar precios, dividir por cantidades, separar productos por comprador, etc... ¿Algún acercamiento a como podría formatear las cadenas con exactitud? Un saludo.

Comment: Aunque la imagen es importante para entender el contexto del problema, para resolverlo resulta ser irrelevante, y la verdadera información que necesitaríamos para poder ayudarte es lo que encuentra el OCR, es decir, el contenido de la variable `result`. ¿Podrías volcar a disco ese texto y adjuntarlo a la pregunta (no como imagen, sino como "código")? Eso nos permitiría comprender su estructura y hacer experimentos con expresiones regulares u otras formas de procesarlo.

Comment: Tienes razón. Queda borrada la última imagen y la sustituyo por el contenido de la variables 'result' y 'final' en el momento de ejecutar el programa.

Comment: En `result` no tienes precisamente lo que quieres conseguir?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Veo complicado dar con una expresión regular que te encaje con el *ticket completo*. Es mucho más sencillo (y aún así se las trae), si procesamos el ticket línea a línea.

En ese caso para cada línea del ticket se puede intentar una expresión regular que separe el nombre del item, la cantidad (el `1x`, pero el `1` podría ser cualquier otro número), el precio unitario (que es lo que va tras la cantidad) y el precio final (que debería ser igual al precio unitario multiplicado por la cantidad).

Si el texto no contuviera errores, no sería tan difícil. Pero vemos que hay líneas en las que el OCR se ha liado porque el ticket tenía una manchita, y aparece una coma donde no debería. O el `1x` ha salido como `1X`, o peor aún como `1):`. El precio en alguno de los items también sale mal, pues a veces el punto separador de decimales es detectado como `,`, o peor aún como `-` en algunos casos.

Lo mejor será entonces intentar una expresión regular que encaje lo que se pueda, y que al menos detecte errores en las líneas en que no ha encajado, e informe al usuario de los problemas (mostrándole esas líneas).

El siguiente código muestra cómo hacerlo. Tiene un bucle en el que va procesando cada línea (previamente las obtiene todas en una lista, eliminando las líneas vacías), excepto la última que es la del total y no se usa. Cada línea se intenta encajar con una expresión regular. Si no se consigue, se informa del error y se pasa a la siguiente. Si se consigue, se extrae la información de los grupos de captura, se convierte a `float` los precios, y se verifica que el precio final coincide con el precio unitario por la cantidad. Si no es así, se informa del error y se salta a otra línea. Para las líneas en las que se ha conseguido extraer con éxito la información, ésta se guarda en un diccionario y se va construyendo una lista de diccionarios.

```
import re

lineas = [l for l in resul.split("\n") if l]

ticket = []   # Lista con los resultados procesados

for linea in lineas[:-1]:
  m = re.match(r'^(.+)\s(\d+)(?:[xX])\s.*?([\d\.,]+?)(?:\s.*?)(\d[\d\.,]*)\s.*?([A-Z])?$', linea)
  if not m:
    print(f"{linea}")
    print("   ERROR. La línea no encaja con el patrón")
    continue  # Ir a por otra

  # Si encajó en el patrón, extraemos la información
  # print(m.groups())
  producto, cantidad, precio_unitario, precio_final, letra = m.groups()
  precio_unitario = float(precio_unitario.replace(",", "."))
  precio_final = float(precio_final.replace(",", "."))
  cantidad = int(cantidad)

  if precio_final != cantidad * precio_unitario:
    print(f"{linea}")
    print("   ERROR. El precio parece no estar bien")
    continue # La saltamos y vamos a por otra

  # Si todo ha ido bien, guardamos la info en un diccionario
  info = { "producto": producto, 
           "cantidad": cantidad,
           "precio_unitario": precio_unitario,
           "precio_final": precio_final,
           "letra": letra
         }
  # Y el diccionario en una lista
  ticket.append(info)
```

Como ves, la expresión regular se las trae. Si necesitas ayuda para entenderla pregunta en un comentario.

Si lo ejecutamos sobre el caso de ejemplo que has suministrado, informa de algunos errores:

```
ESTROPAJO INUXIDABLE 1): 0.45 0,45 0
   ERROR. La línea no encaja con el patrón
CDRAZON RUMANA BJA 1x 1-49 1.49 A
   ERROR. El precio parece no estar bien
ENSALADA 4 ESTACIUNE 1X 0-59 0,59 A
   ERROR. El precio parece no estar bien
```

Efectivamente vemos que las líneas que detecta como malas no tienen la estructura correcta. La primera porque no aparece el `1x` y las demás porque el precio está mal y no encaja en la fórmula cantidad x precio_unitario = precio_final.

El resto de ítems que sí encajaron, están en la lista `ticket`:

```
[{'producto': 'CERVEZA FRANZISKANER', 'cantidad': 1, 'precio_unitario': 5.95, 'precio_final': 5.95, 'letra': 'C'},
 {'producto': 'LIMPIADOR VINAGRE 1L', 'cantidad': 1, 'precio_unitario': 0.75, 'precio_final': 0.75, 'letra': 'C'},
 {'producto': 'MONSTER BEBIDA ENERG', 'cantidad': 1, 'precio_unitario': 1.0, 'precio_final': 1.0, 'letra': 'B'},
 {'producto': 'ACEITUNA R/ANCH 150G', 'cantidad': 1, 'precio_unitario': 0.55, 'precio_final': 0.55, 'letra': 'B'},
 {'producto': 'ARROZ REDUNDO EXTRA', 'cantidad': 1, 'precio_unitario': 0.72, 'precio_final': 0.72, 'letra': 'A'},
 {'producto': 'MAS REGANAS AC.0L', 'cantidad': 1, 'precio_unitario': 0.66, 'precio_final': 0.66, 'letra': 'B'},
 {'producto': 'PALOMITAS SAL MICRO', 'cantidad': 1, 'precio_unitario': 0.79, 'precio_final': 0.79, 'letra': 'B'},
 {'producto': 'BARRAS PRE00 UFERTA', 'cantidad': 1, 'precio_unitario': 1.0, 'precio_final': 1.0, 'letra': 'A'},
 {'producto': 'MAGGI PASTA URIENTAL', 'cantidad': 1, 'precio_unitario': 1.5, 'precio_final': 1.5, 'letra': 'B'},
 {'producto': 'BULSA BASURA IFA', 'cantidad': 1, 'precio_unitario': 1.3, 'precio_final': 1.3, 'letra': 'C'},
 {'producto': 'SALAMI REVILLAS 85 0', 'cantidad': 1, 'precio_unitario': 0.95, 'precio_final': 0.95, 'letra': 'B'},
 {'producto': 'SALCHICHON 85 GR', 'cantidad': 1, 'precio_unitario': 0.95, 'precio_final': 0.95, 'letra': 'B'},
 {'producto': 'FILETE PECHUGA PAVO', 'cantidad': 1, 'precio_unitario': 4.42, 'precio_final': 4.42, 'letra': 'B'},
 {'producto': 'PIZZA JAMDN Y [JUESO ‘', 'cantidad': 1, 'precio_unitario': 1.75, 'precio_final': 1.75, 'letra': 'B'},
 {'producto': 'ENSALADA 4 ESTACIONE', 'cantidad': 1, 'precio_unitario': 0.59, 'precio_final': 0.59, 'letra': 'A'}
]
```

Si quieres imprimirlo bonito, puedes usar el bucle siguiente (que de paso te calcula la suma total, si bien no coincidirá en este caso con la que muestra el ticket real, debido a que hubo tres items no procesados):

```
total = 0
for item in ticket:
  total += item["precio_final"]
  print("{producto:25} {cantidad}x {precio_unitario:5.2f} = {precio_final:5.2f}".format(**item))
print("-"*42)
print(f"TOTAL: {total:35.2f}")
```

Muestra lo siguiente:

```
CERVEZA FRANZISKANER      1x  5.95 =  5.95
LIMPIADOR VINAGRE 1L      1x  0.75 =  0.75
MONSTER BEBIDA ENERG      1x  1.00 =  1.00
ACEITUNA R/ANCH 150G      1x  0.55 =  0.55
ARROZ REDUNDO EXTRA       1x  0.72 =  0.72
MAS REGANAS AC.0L         1x  0.66 =  0.66
PALOMITAS SAL MICRO       1x  0.79 =  0.79
BARRAS PRE00 UFERTA       1x  1.00 =  1.00
MAGGI PASTA URIENTAL      1x  1.50 =  1.50
BULSA BASURA IFA          1x  1.30 =  1.30
SALAMI REVILLAS 85 0      1x  0.95 =  0.95
SALCHICHON 85 GR          1x  0.95 =  0.95
FILETE PECHUGA PAVO       1x  4.42 =  4.42
PIZZA JAMDN Y [JUESO ‘    1x  1.75 =  1.75
ENSALADA 4 ESTACIONE      1x  0.59 =  0.59
------------------------------------------
TOTAL:                               22.88
```

Comment: Buenísima respuesta compañero.

Answer (score 1):

puedes hacerlo asi:

> En mi caso no me trae los `1x` por lo que tube que crearlos:

```
try:
    from PIL import Image
except ImportError:
    import Image
import pytesseract
import re
import os

#Lee la imagen.
img = Image.open("IRBYK.jpg")

#Transforma la imgen en texto.
pytesseract.pytesseract.tesseract_cmd = 'C:/Program Files (x86)/Tesseract-OCR/tesseract'
result = pytesseract.image_to_string(img)

#Muestra el texto resultante.
factura={"items":[], "price": [], "total":[]}

for x in result.split("\n"):
    # validamos no sean lineas vacias
    if len(x.strip()):
        # cambiamos comas por puntos y eliminamos los saltos de linea
        nstring = x.replace(",", ".").strip()
        # extraemos solo los precios
        if re.search("^[0-9]?.[0-9]+\s[/w]?",nstring):
            # removemos caracteres especiales
            precios =re.sub("[^A-Za-z0-9.\s]+",'',nstring)
            # eliminamos espacios de mas y saltos de linea
            precios = re.sub("[\s]+", " ",precios).strip()
            #agregamos al dict price eliminado los espacios 
            factura["price"].append(precios)

        # validamos que sea la compra
        elif "COMPRA." in nstring:
            # extraemos solo el total 
            total = re.findall("\d+\.\d+",nstring)
            #agregamos al dict price eliminado los saltos de linea
            factura["total"].append(total[0].strip())
        else:
            # lo que nos queda es los nombres de productos que agregamos
            # a el dict items
            factura["items"].append(nstring)

# escribimos el nuevo archivo
with open("final.txt","w") as f:
    for k,v in enumerate(factura["items"]):
        cantidad = factura['price'][k].split(" ")
        i=0
        while cantidad[0]*i < cantidad[1]: i+=1

    print(f"{factura['items'][k]:<30} {i}x {cantidad[0]} = {cantidad[1]} {cantidad[2]}")
    f.write(f"{factura['items'][k]:<30} {i}x {cantidad[0]} = {cantidad[1]} {cantidad[2]}\n")

    print("{} {:>33}".format("TOTAL FACTURA",factura['total'][0]))
    f.write("{} {:>33}".format("TOTAL FACTURA",factura['total'][0]))
    f.close()
```

**resultado:**

```
CERVEZA FRANZISKANER           1x 5.95 = 5.95 C
LIMPIADOR VINAGRE 1L           1x 0.75 = 0.75 C
MONSTER BEBIDA ENERG           1x 1.00 = 1.00 B
ACEITUNA R/ANCH 150G           1x 0.55 = 0.55 B
ARROZ REDONDO EXTRA            1x 0.72 = 0.72 A
MAS REGANAS AC.OL              1x 0.66 = 0.56 B
PALOMITAS SAL MICRO            1x 0.79 = 0.79 B
BARRAS PRECO OFERTA            1x 1.00 = 1.00 A
MAGGI PASTA ORIENTAL           1x 1.50 = 1.50 B
BOLSA BASURA IFA               1x 1.30 = 1.30 C
SALAMI REVILLAS 85 G           1x 0.95 = 0.95 B
SALCHICHON 85 GR               1x 0.95 = 0.95 B
FILETE PECHUGA PAVO            1x 4.42 = 4.42 B
ESTROPAJO INOXIDABLE           1x 0.45 = 0.45 C
CORAZON ROMANA BJA             1x 1.49 = 1.49 A
ENSALADA 4 ESTACIONE |         1x 0.59 = 0.59 A
PIZZA JAMON Y QUESO            1x 1.75 = 1.75 B
ENSALADA 4 ESTACIONE           1x 0.59 = 0.59 A
TOTAL FACTURA                             25.41
```